iOS Mobile App Installation Error as "Cannot Install Application as certificate for www.abc.com is not valid”

IpadOS16.7.10(20H350)

I am getting an error while installing my app using a link. Https://www.bazsoft.com/Mbaz.aspx
Error- "Cannot Install Application as certificate for www.bazsoft.com is not valid”
I have an Apple Developer Account and
Below are the software version:

Cordova iOS : 6.1.1
XCODE : 16.1
Angular :Angular 17
Node : v20.10.0
Npm : v10.2.3
Cordova : v12.0.0

Below are the Steps Performed to debug..
1.Checked the Bundle ID/ App ID is same as configured in XCODE in General tab-> Identity(com.abc.Myapp)
2.Checked the Expiry Date of Certificates,Provisioning Profiles.
3.Deleted all the certificates from key-chain Access and re-downloaded.
4.Removed the ios platform and added again
5.Deleted the xcode derived data
6.Code signing identities are matched with provisioning profile
7.Tried with enabling “Automatically Manage Signing” .
8.macOS and XCODE are updated
9.While building the cordova ios(cordova build ios) in mac terminal showing below message as
**     Signing Identity : “Sign to Run Locally”**
PF below .plist code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>items</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>assets</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>software-package</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://www.bazsoft.com/Files/MBAZ.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>display-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://www.bazsoft.com/Files/MBAZ.ipa</string>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>kind</key>
                    <string>full-size-image</string>
                    <key>url</key>
                    <string>https://www.bazsoft.com/Files/MBAZ.ipa</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>metadata</key>
            <dict>
                <key>bundle-identifier</key>
                <string>com.cigna.mbaz</string>
                <key>bundle-version</key>
                <string>2.0.764</string>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software</string>
                <key>platform-identifier</key>
                <string>com.apple.platform.iphoneos</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>MBAZ</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

